# Opening JQuery Dialogs from JQuery Dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am currently working on a bit of JS, and have run into an interesting issue.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, as I don't see any reason it shouldn't work, but I'm not getting any results.  I am running the following code:

```
$('#am_schedDetailModal').dialog('option', 'buttons', [{
    text: 'Delete',
    click: function () {
        $('#am_confirmationDialog').html('Are you certain you wish to delete this entry?');
        $('#am_confirmationDialog').dialog('option', 'buttons', [{
            text: 'Yes',
            click: function () {
                deleteScheduledEntryAt(cellID);
                $('#am_schedDetailModal').html('');
                $('#am_schedDetailModal').dialog('close');
                $('div', this).html('');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }, {
            text: 'No',
            click: function () {
                $('div', this).html('');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }]);

        $('#am_confirmationDialog').dialog('open');
    }
}]);
```

The problem is that when I run this code, the second dialog doesn't appear.  The first dialog appears, and the other buttons work fine, but the 'Delete' button has no effect at all.  There is no error (according to FireBug), but nothing shows up.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**  Thanks to Kevin van Hoorn, it appears that this was a pretty simple mistake- I created the second dialog in the code, but forgot to actually initialize it.

Comment: Just to be sure, it's not simply caught behind the existing dialog is it?

Comment: No, I tried dragging it around and the second dialog was not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append that div to something before trying to use it.
Like

```
document.append('<div id="am_confirmationDialog" />');
```

Comment: The div is already present in the HTML for the page, right below the div `am_schedDetailModal`.

Comment: Is it also initalized as a dialog?

Comment: Wow... I haven't felt that stupid in a long time.  I completely forgot the initialization.  Thanks!